# Get HTML from url

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, httprequest

I'm trying to use C#'s HttpWebRequest to get page source based on url.

In the browser, I'm doing this way:

1. I go to http://brokercheck.finra.org/Search/Search.aspx
2. Insert a zipcode, say 00501. and do a search.

I am then redirected to 
http://brokercheck.finra.org/Search/SearchResults.aspx?SearchGroup=Individual&IndlText=&FirmText=&ZipCode=00544&ZipRadius=5&PageNumber=1
This page's html is what I want.

The simple way of using a get method of HttpWebRequest  doe not work. It will just get the html of search page.

I then tried to send a post and get cookies and send a get request with the cookies.
But still, the response html was the search page's html.

Comment: What do you want back from that request?

Comment: neoistheone, I want to get the page source of http://brokercheck.finra.org/Search/SearchResults.aspx?SearchGroup=Individual&IndlText=&FirmText=&ZipCode=00544&ZipRadius=5&PageNumber=1

Comment: It's not apparent to me that this is a `GET`. I would say you really need to analyze what's sent to the server (e.g. headers, body, request type).

Comment: Try to do a POST Request with these parameters to "Search.aspx" instead of "SearchResults.aspx"

Comment: I did analyzed see the picture below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use http sniffer tool(WireShark, or HttpWatch)  to capture the http request and responses through web browser.

The search.aspx page uses : onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$phContent$ucUnifiedSearch$lbtnFreeFormSearch", "", true, "", "", false, false))" to submit the request.

The SearchResults.aspx page may use some request header information(e.g previos page) to find out if it is a direct access.

You need find out the exact data in the request for SearchResults.aspx.